# Concat two mp4 files with ffmpeg without losing quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to concatenate 2 videos using ffmpeg.  I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -scodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb i0.ts
```

But the mp4 file I get looks much worse then the source file.

Here is the information about both the files

```
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output1.mp4':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 1
   compatible_brands: isom
   creation_time   : 2013-06-13 15:40:36
   Duration: 00:00:15.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2053 kb/s
   Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1931 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr,   12800 tbn, 50 tbc
   Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s

  Input #0, mpegts, from 'i0.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:15.64, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 1382 kb/s
  Program 1 
  Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: Libav
  Stream #0.0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
  Stream #0.1[0x101](und): Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: sorry. Then i concat them with ffmpeg -i "concat:i0.ts|i1.ts" output1111.mp4. But the problem is that the quality is bad already when i make ts-files

Comment: yes, exactly. All are equall

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg/11175851#11175851

Answer (score 43):

Consider using the [`concat` demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1). This way you can avoid creating temporary, lossy intermediate files and skip an extra step of re-encoding.

**Note:** All inputs must have the same stream types (same formats, same time base, etc.).

1. Create a text file and include the paths and names of each file to concatenate (or "join"). Example file, `input.txt`:

   ```
   file '/home/jenia/input1.mp4'
   file '/home/jenia/input2.mp4'
   file '/home/jenia/input3.mp4'
   ```
2. Now you can use the `concat` demuxer:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4
   ```

If you do not have this feature, then either your ffmpeg is too old, or you're using a "fake" ffmpeg from the libav fork.

Easy to use static builds are available for Linux, OS X, and Windows via the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page, or you can follow a [step-by-step guide to compile ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Also see:

- [How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files)
- [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and helped me merge 2 .mov files from my iPhone 6. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The quickest 1-liner would be:

```
ls Movie\ Part\ * | while read line; do echo file \'$line\'; done | ffmpeg -f concat -i - -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Any chance to get such a 1-onliner for windows command line?

Comment: On Linux I used this oneliner: `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i <(find . -type f -name '*' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n" | sort) -c copy output.mkv` (mkv accepts more codecs than mp4, but you could also try it with mp4). The `-safe 0` is for recent ffmpeg versions complaining about **Unsafe file name**, and the `-type f` is for only listing files. I added `| sort` to sort the files alphabetically; because `find` reads them in order as saved on filesystem. Works also for files with whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to erik's request for a Windows one-liner - here is llogan's solution written as such:

```
(type NUL > input.txt) && (for /F "usebackq delims=" %x in (`dir /B *.mp4`) do echo file '%x' >> input.txt) && (ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4)
```

Which is actually the following 3 commands glued together:

Overwrite any pre-existing `input.txt` file with an empty file:

```
type NUL > input.txt
```

For each file matching `*.mp4`, append `file filename.mp4` to `input.txt`.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %x in (`dir /B *.mp4`) do echo file '%x' >> input.txt
```

Finally run FFMPEG as demonstrated in llogan's answer.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

`*/ EDIT`

- You can easily resolve it using this ***[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1609481/969781)*** from ***[@Gyan](https://superuser.com/users/114058/gyan)***

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:File1.mp4|File2.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy  -codec copy .\output.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:File_1.mp4|File_2.mp4|File_3.mp4|File_4.mp4|...| File_nn.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy -codec copy .\output.mp4
```

`EDIT */`

---

This can be done by one line:

```
>input.txt (for %x in (*.mp4)do @echo file '%~x') && ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy .\output.mp4
```

---

1. Create/Overwrite file `>input.txt` with (command block) output

   ```
     >input.txt (for %x in (*.mp4)do @echo file '%~x')
   ```
2. List all files with name.extension to output with layout `file '%~x'`

   ```
     >input.txt (for %x in (*.mp4)do @echo file '%~x')
   ```
3. Only if last (block command) execution `return 0` (by operator `&&`), then run `ffmpeg` command:

   ```
    && ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy .\output.mp4
   ```

- You can also work with different drivers/folders:

  ```
  >"%temp%\input.txt" (for %x in ("d:\movies\last\*.mp4")do @echo file '%~x') && "c:\ffmepg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -safe 0 -f concat -i "%temp%\input.txt" -codec copy "d:\movies\last\concat\output.mp4"
  ```