# ffmpeg not copying audio from concatenated VOB files. Says sample rate not set

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a some vob files that I'm trying to concatenate and write out to an mkv. I initially tried:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_02_1.VOB|VTS_02_2.VOB|VTS_02_3.VOB|VTS_02_4.VOB|VTS_02_5.VOB" -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 21 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

But that didn't copy the audio at all:

```
ffmpeg version N-89977-gddd851f7cb-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-11) 20171206
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavdevice    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[mpeg @ 0x54fcb80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Audio: ac3, 0 channels): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'concat:VTS_02_1.VOB|VTS_02_2.VOB|VTS_02_3.VOB|VTS_02_4.VOB|VTS_02_5.VOB':
  Duration: 02:30:25.48, start: 0.233567, bitrate: 3950 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 0 channels
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5586ec0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5586ec0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5586ec0] profile High, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0x5586ec0] 264 - core 155 r69 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=21.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.9.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.10.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
```

So I explicitly map the streams:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_02_1.VOB|VTS_02_2.VOB|VTS_02_3.VOB|VTS_02_4.VOB|VTS_02_5.VOB" -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 21 -c:a copy -map 0:1 -map 0:2 output.mkv
```

But this time it says the sample rate is not set:

```
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-11) 20171206
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavdevice    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[mpeg @ 0x5ae7b80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Audio: ac3, 0 channels): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'concat:VTS_02_1.VOB|VTS_02_2.VOB|VTS_02_3.VOB|VTS_02_4.VOB|VTS_02_5.VOB':
  Duration: 02:30:25.48, start: 0.233567, bitrate: 3950 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 0 channels
File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5af1800] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5af1800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5af1800] profile High, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0x5af1800] 264 - core 155 r69 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=21.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x5af0980] sample rate not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the log says, set high analyzeduration and probesize values.

`ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M -i "concat:VTS_02_1.VOB|VTS_02_2.VOB|VTS_02_3.VOB|VTS_02_4.VOB|VTS_02_5.VOB" -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 21 -c:a copy output.mkv`

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up discovering this accidentally after converting the audio to mp3 (which got rid of this error), but then only discovering the subtitles after I used `analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M`.

Comment: The `-analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M` args was solution! Tks! S2