# I want to concatenate two .mp4 files but ffmpeg shows an error all over:

Tags: ffmpeg, video, python

```
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 484090, current: 481360; changing to 484091. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

The command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy merged.mp4
```

and because of the error the .mp4 file plays one video correctly in the merged.mp4 but when the first video's runtime is over the second one fails to play.

Please suggest a fix or an alternative (I only want to use a script as I want to automate merging of multiple videos *fast*).

Comment: From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/607384/432690): "All inputs must have the same stream types (same formats, same time base, etc.)". Do your input files fulfill this?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the different configurations/formats of your input files, like fps. You need to convert all the files to the sample configuration, e.g., apply the following command to all input files.

```
ffmpeg -y -i f_current.mp4 -vf "setpts=1.25*PTS" -r 15 f_current_.mp4
```

That command will convert the file `f_current.mp4` to `f_current_.mp4` with 15 fps. Then you need to update your list.txt with the output files. You can modify the output fps and/or other settings depending on your needs. But, it's noted that the above command needs to be applied to all input files to make them have the same configurations.